# meta-virtualization rocko branch unable to locate docker package

Tags: docker, yocto

I am trying to build docker on the rocko branch, but I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to install packages. Command
 '/media/storage/updater/rocko_poky/test_docker/poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-get  install --force-yes --allow-unauthenticated docker
 packagegroup-core-boot run-postinsts' returned 100: Reading package
 lists... Building dependency tree...
 E: Unable to locate package docker
```

My build configuration is:

```
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.4.2"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "rocko:6b744113ad3e564d1cb05411816b103d99fd84dc"
meta-oe              
meta-networking      
meta-filesystems     
meta-python          = "rocko:dacfa2b1920e285531bec55cd2f08743390aaf57"
meta-virtualization  = "rocko:bd77388f31929f38e7d4cc9c711f0f83f563007e"
```

The image I am building

> core-image-minimal

The only changes added to local.conf are:

```
 DISTRO_FEATURES_append=“ virtualization” 
 CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "docker"
```

The machine I am running the build on is

> Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)

It really seems to me that the docker .deb file fails to get built.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the package_deb class somehow. I ran into the same issue here and switching to ipk fixed it.

i.e. put a setting like this into your local.conf:
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"

Comment: yes, thank you, I did the same. I hope they will solve it for deb packages also. rpm also works, btw.